# How to add multiple browsers to Codeception for Browser Stack

Tags: codeception

I am trying to configure my acceptance.suite.yml in Codeception to allow me to run the test in various browsers on Browser Stack.

```html
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
  enabled:
    - WebDriver
  config:
    WebDriver:
      url: 'http://www.heyday.co.nz'
      host: 'hub.browserstack.com'
      port: 80
      browsers: firefox
      capabilities:
```

How would I add say, IE8 and Safari for example? Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Environments](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments).

That chapter describes your use case, but I will copy some details to avoid giving a link only answer.

For cases where you need to run tests with different configurations you can define different config environments.

`acceptance.suite.yml`

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - \Helper\Acceptance
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
            browser: 'firefox'

env:
    phantom:
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'phantomjs'

    chrome:
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'chrome'

    firefox:
        # nothing changed
```

You can easily switch between those configs by running tests with --env option. To run tests only for PhantomJS you need to pass --env phantom option:
`php codecept.phar run acceptance --env phantom`

To run tests in all 3 browsers, just list all the environments:

`php codecept.phar run acceptance --env phantom --env chrome --env firefox`

Comment: I had to add `path=`''` to the WebDriver config for Firefox.